# Does MongoDB store keys of repetetive entries every time? Best way to store thousands of data-rows that are always accessed together

Tags: database, mongodb, rdbms

I am planning to create a Collection of "users" in MongoDB consisting of documents like this:

```
{
    "name": "Example",
    "age": 100,
    "data": [
        {
            "key1": value1,
            "key2": value2,
            "key3": value3
        },
        {
            "key1": value1,
            "key2": value2,
            "key3": value3
        },
        {
            "key1": value1,
            "key2": value2,
            "key3": value3
        }
    ]
}
```

with the "data"-array containing tens of thousands of entries. All entries have the same structure with identical keys. Does MongoDB really store the Strings I use as keys for every single element in the array? As the values are small numbers, the repetetive keys would consume more storage space than the values.

I am uncertain whether to use a schemafull oder schemaless db for this. The elements in "data" are added one by one (1 every second) and in series (no random writes). If I want to do something with the "data", I always need all data-entries of a user at the same time. If I would use a schemafull database, I would have a giant table with the entries of "data" associating them with a userId. It feels a bit wrong to write thousands of entries in individual rows and always accessing them together. Is there a good way to basically do a relation-free schemaful table inside of MongoDB documents? Or a schemaful database to store thousands of entries grouped together?

Do you have ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Yes, it does. However the WiredTiger storage engine compresses the data. When you have verbose key names and very small data, then the keys may consume more disk space than the actual values.

Comment: Bear in mind, the max. size of a document is 16MiByte. If you add an entry to `data` array every second, then you will hit this limit rather soon.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The document size limit could acutally turn into a problem. So I am probably switching to a schemafull db like MySQL or MariaDB. It´s still feeling a bit wrong though, having a table for data with thousands of lines per user